# MFC Saving Custom Header Column Widths

Tags: mfc

So I'm just learning MFC to see if I want to start using it over normal Win32 programming.  I have a SDI MFC application setup.  I have a view with members that create a `CTreeCtrl` and `CHeaderCtrl`.   I have a `CDwordArray` setup as `m_ColWidths` that is currently in my View class, but using MFC, should this be in the document class instead since I'll want to save and restore it to keep the users widths when program exits?  I guess even though it's only part of the view it's still data and use `GetDocument()` to reference them?

TIA!!

Comment: _"I guess even though it's only part of the view it's still data and use GetDocument() to reference them"_: yes you can do that. Read also my comment to IInspectable''s answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application state should not be stored in the document. The purpose of the [CDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdocument-class)(-derived) class is:

> A document represents the unit of data that the user typically opens with the File Open command and saves with the File Save command.
>
> `CDocument` supports standard operations such as creating a document, loading it, and saving it. The framework manipulates documents using the interface defined by `CDocument`.

The designated entity to store application state (e.g. size and visibility of UI elements) is the [CWinAppEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwinappex-class)(-derived) implementation:

> `CWinAppEx` handles the application state, saves the state to the registry, loads the state from the registry, [...].

Comment: Hmm. IMO it depends entirely on the application and on the kind of document. Storing the column widths in the CDocument may make sense or not. The columns widths could be part of the document, which is typically what we have with Excel documents.

Comment: @jab: You are conflating different concepts here: content and representation. Excel doesn't store UI state in its document either. It stores the size of cells, and the UI adjusts to the space requirements when loading the document. Excel doesn't store your view settings (e.g. when changing the *display* width or height of a column/row) for cells, that aren't explicitly sized.

Comment: I maintain: like in Excel the size of cells are part of the document, in the OP's app the size of the column widths may be part of the _document state_ or not (maybe you want to reduce the size of a column to zero but only for a specific document and not application wide). Storing the state of expansion of a CTreeCtrl in the document may also make sense or not (Visual studio does this for the Solution Explorer). It really depends on the kind of document and the kind of application.

Comment: @jab: Again, you are conflating concepts. Excel stores information like formatting of cells, *not* information how they are viewed (e.g. zoom level). Likewise, Visual Studio doesn't store view state in its *solution* document. It persists that information in a separate store, much like MFC uses the registry for persisting application state.

Comment: I'm not mentioning zoom level, but column widths, which are clearly part of the .xls state and not application state.

Comment: So `LoadState` and `SaveState` or should it be `LoadCustomState` and `SaveCustomState`  or even the `PreLoadState` and `PreSaveState` ?   You know what would be awesome if anybody knows of one, a flowchart that shows the flow and the elements could show where common items go (color coded or in the element itself) ?